# PHP Replace strange characters to normal Latin

Tags: php, pdf, non-ascii-characters

I am processing Instagram feeds for a printing tool.
PDF can't process most exotic chars so it will print a block.

Text which I don't know how to replace:

~         ~

First of all I don't know how these type of chars are called?
I want to replace them, or just remove them.

Tried several things and posts, (Russian chars are already removed), but can't find a solution for this one.

Comment: https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/mathematical_alphanumeric_symbols/list.htm